# Abstracting Java Annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I have a particular situation where I would like to create an annotation that can accept a "base" annotation as one of its parameters:

```
public @interface Fleet
{
    int fleetSize();
    Vehicle fleetType();
}
```

Where `@Vehicle` is a "base" annotation for different types of vehicles that will accept different parameters that make sense for them:

```
public @interface Vehicle {}

public @interface Car extends Vehicle {
    boolean is2WheelDrive();
}

public @interface Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
    String manufacturer();
}
```

So that the `@Fleet` annotation can be used like so:

```
// A fleet of 20 Hyabusas
@Fleet(20, @Motorcycle("Hyabusas"))
public void doSomething() {
    // ...
}

// A fleet of 5 4-Wheel-drive cars
@Fleet(5, @Car(false))
public void doSomethingElse() {
    // ...
}
```

Now, first off, a few things: yes I know this example illustrates a *terrible* design! And I know that you can't extend an annotation with Java.

Given those two known evils, how could I refactor those code snippets anyways so that the following constraints are met:

- The `@Fleet` annotation can be passed either a `@Car` or `@Motorcycle`
- `@Car` and `@Motorcycle` accept different (both in quantity and type) arguments

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really do this.

The normal approach would be to apply both @Fleet and one of @Car and @Motorcycle to the class. Not ideal, admittedly.